# describe block in test doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I am using mocha.

```js
describe('test', async function ()  {
  let a;
  

  before(async () => {
    a = 10;
  })


  it("ff", () => {

  })

  describe("nice", () => {
    const b = a;
    console.log(b);
    it("ss", () => {
      console.log("nice")
    })
  })
})
```

It seems like `console.log(b)` prints undefined. Even though `before` block gets executed first .

Any idea `b` is undefined and not 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `describe` functions will be called before calling the hooks. The order of the tests (`it`) will preserver the order that you want. For example, in the callback where you print `"nice"`, `a` is 10.

> When a test file is loaded, Mocha executes all of its suites and finds–but does not execute–any hooks and tests therein.

Source: https://mochajs.org/#serial-mode (step 8)